# what is the difference between a symlink , junction , hard link and so on?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, junction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between NTFS hard links and directory junctions?](https://superuser.com/questions/67870/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-hard-links-and-directory-junctions)

well just got a litlle confused about all of them.
so any explanation?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229116/ntfs-junctions-vs-symbolic-links-for-directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS documentation is pretty clear: [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Creating Symbolic Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363878%28VS.85%29.aspx). What specifically do you need to know apart from what's on the MSDN pages?

Comment: You should at least include the basic information here. SO should be self contained.