# AdwCleaner finds my symlink as a threat. Why?

Tags: windows-7, security, junction

Malwarebytes AdwCleaner finds my hard link (aka directory junction) as a threat.

Why is this? Or is it normal for this type of links to be considered a threat by such programs?
And if it's not normal, what should I do about it?

Windows 7 SP1 x86

Many thanks!

Comment: It may not matter in this case but it looks to me that [symlinks, hardlinks and directory junctions are different animals](https://superuser.com/a/902082/432690). You seem to confuse all three.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski I'm talking about the /J switch. And I'm not sure about terminology, but for example, this article called "The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links" uses the term hard link for /J, saying that it's also knows as a directory junction: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/